# how do i change my terminal from username@server to username@client on ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-server

am trying to configure DNS for my home network , am done with the server side but still trying configure the client side , but don't know how to change the terminal from @server to @client
[Ubuntu server default terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvzdR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is changing your "hostname"

Try using the command below:

> $ sudo hostnamectl set-hostname client

Further reading: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/change-hostname-linux